# how to add prefix in Predefined Namespace Prefixes at dbpedia endpoint

Tags: installation, dbpedia, virtuoso

I have installed Virtuoso on my server. It is working fine with most queries, but giving problem if i use prefix in the query for, e.g., **`dbpedia-owl`**

query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?dbpedia_link 
WHERE 
  { ?dbpedia_link  rdf:type  <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Film> } 
LIMIT 10
```

This works fine and gives me correct output.

But when i replace the **`<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Film>`** with **`dbpedia-owl:Film`** it gives **`Undefined namespace prefix at 'dbpedia-owl' error`**. Suppose I enter below query, it throws error.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?dbpedia_link 
WHERE { ?dbpedia_link  rdf:type  dbpedia-owl:Film } 
LIMIT 10
```

I check in Predefined Namespace Prefixes; `dbpedia-owl` is not present. I want to know how to add a prefix to the Predefined Namespace Prefixes.

Comment: I know if i add prefix dbepedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> that error will go but i want to add prefix in Predefined Namespace Prefixes

Answer (score 3):

To add prefix in Predefined Namespace Prefixes, the command is as shown below. This command is to add prefix `dbpedia-owl` to predefined Namespaces Prefixes

```
DB.DBA.XML_SET_NS_DECL ('dbpedia-owl', 'http://dbpedia.org/ontology/', 2);
```

Comment: More details can be found here http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/fn_xml_set_ns_decl.html